# Spinner setSelection( ) does not work without postDelayed Runnable

Tags: android, android-spinner

unitSpinner sets fromSpinner and toSpinner adapters based on selection like this :

```
unitSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    setUnitSpinnerAdapter(areaHeaders);
                    break;
                .
                .
                .
                case 12:
                    setUnitSpinnerAdapter(volumeHeaders);
                    break;
            }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

setUnitSpinnerAdapter :

```
public void setUnitSpinnerAdapter(String[] headers) {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, headers);
    adapterUnits.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    fromSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    toSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I call this

```
unitSpinner.setSelection(getIndex(unitSpinner, cur.getString(1)));
fromSpinner.setSelection(getIndex(fromSpinner, cur.getString(2)));
toSpinner.setSelection(getIndex(toSpinner, cur.getString(3)));
```

getIndex :

```
private int getIndex(Spinner spinner, String myString) {
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getCount(); i++) {
        if (spinner.getItemAtPosition(i).toString().equals(myString)) {
            index = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

fromSpinner and toSpinner adapters are set to new values as unitSpinner selection changes but setSelection on them does not work since getIndex compares old adapters and returns index as 0 unless I do this :

```
unitSpinner.setSelection(getIndex(unitSpinner, cur.getString(1)));
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                         fromSpinner.setSelection(getIndex(fromSpinner, cur.getString(2)));
                         toSpinner.setSelection(getIndex(toSpinner, cur.getString(3)));
                    }
                }, 1000);
```

This makes my app seem slow as I have to wait 1000ms to see changes. Setting smaller wait time like 100ms does not work everytime. What should I do?

Comment: instead of `postDelayed` just use `post`, no need for a magic `1000` ms

Comment: `post` works but only second time I run that function. I need a way to execute `fromSpinner.setSelection(...)` only after `setUnitSpinnerAdapter(...)` function is over.

Comment: what is your real problem? why to use Handler at all?

Comment: For each item in unitSpinner, from and to Spinners have different arrays. But before unitSpinner sets the array, getIndex() gets called and does not find required string as it searches in old array.

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: @kenji No. I'm still using the postDelayed method.

Comment: postDelay madde some bugs when spinners should create and fill automatically one after one... check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067757/dynamically-setselection-of-spinner-do-not-trigger-onitemselectedlistener

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
fromSpinnerAdapter.notifdatachanged();
```

Comment: what is it? adapter has no such method. even if you mean `notifyDataSetChanged` it has nothing to do with OP problem

Comment: like adapter update datas after u setSelection.so when u delay ,it become right . what's cur? more detail .

Comment: fromSpinner's datas  change after u use setSelection();