# Dynamically setSelection of spinner, do not trigger OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android, select, spinner, onitemclicklistener

I have a activity that have many cascaded spinner and after select first one, second spinner initialize and fill data and  after select item from second, third spinner initialize and fill data and so on.

for each spinner I create them like this and it is iterative:

```
public ArrayList<MaterialSpinner> spinnerlist = new ArrayList<>();

public void createView(){
 final MaterialSpinner spinner = new MaterialSpinner(context);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){//...after select item next spinner creates with calling createView() iteratively}
        loadSpinnerData(); // set adapter and more
        spinnerlist.add(spinner);
}
```

every things go right when select is by user, but when I use `setSelection(positionOfItem)` Dynamically, unfortunately

`spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()`

do not calls. I do not know why this happens.

```
   for (int i = 0; i < some_value; i++) {

            int positionOfItem = get_proper_position;
            spinnerList.get(i).setSelection(positionOfItem); //this not trigger onItemSelect!
        }
```

the problem is here. spinner size is 1 in first time, but after setselection , listener do not calls and second spinner do not creates.

I also thought this is because of time consuming action so try to use a run-able and post some delay but it not worked.

Comment: I asuming you are doing setSelection before initializing setOnItemSelectedListner. it always hould call setOnItemSelectedListner. Please check that scenario and please share your code

Comment: @MiralBhalani I updated the question. first spiner is created and initialized and added to list but it's on select do not work

Comment: can you give some information about categoriesId what is in that?

Comment: Can you please try to move loadSpinnerData(); before    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()

Comment: @MiralBhalani it is not working

Comment: onItemSelecteListner will invok only when any new item is selected which is diffrent from previous one 
OnItemClicklistner will invok every time when item is selected even it is same

so check once that are you selecting any item by default inside of loadSpinnerData()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125827/discussion-between-miral-bhalani-and-kenji).

Comment: @MiralBhalani, that is worth saying again - with a bit more care!... So, `OnItemSelectedListener`'s `onItemSelected()` will only be invoked when a **new** item is selected (i.e., when the selection is different from the previous selection). However, `OnItemClicklistener`'s `onItemClick()` will be invoked **every time** an item is selected (i.e., even if it's same as the previous selection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally find a creepy solution. it seems the problem is with android system that need some time to create item and views. 
when I call `onClickListener` of first spinner it should create second one and fill data and it is time consuming action. so I had to put delay for each Item with variable intervals:

```
for (int i = 0; i < some_value; i++) {
            selectItemOfSpinner(i);
        }


private void selectItemOfSpinner(final int i) {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MaterialSpinner spinner = spinnerList.get(i);
            int positionOfItem = get_proper_position;
            spinner.setSelection(positionOfItem, true);
        }
    }, 50*i);

}
```

this solved my problem and all spinners creates and fills properly. but in some slow device the delay time should increase and this is why i said creepy way. I working on this and I will update the solution if I find a better way.

Comment: Instead of postDelayed just use post. This will postpone the code execution inside run until the layout is drawn. No need to set arbitrary time  for postponing.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to accomplish is achievable with [performItemClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#performItemClick(android.view.View,%20int,%20long))

```
for (int i = 0; i < some_value; i++) {

        int positionOfItem = get_proper_position;
        MaterialSpinner spinner = spinnerList.get(i);
        spinner.setSelection(positionOfItem);

        View itemView = (View)spinner.getChildAt(positionOfItem);
        long itemId = your_spinner.getAdapter().getItemId(positionOfItem);

        spinner.performItemClick(itemView, positionOfItem, itemId);
}
```

`setSelection` doesn't fire `OnItemSelectedListener` but `performItemClick` does.

Comment: I will check and inform you

Comment: (View)spinner.getChildAt(positionOfItem); return null

Comment: `int positionOfItem = get_proper_position;` what does positionOfItem returns?

Comment: it is int positionOfItem = spinnerList.get(i).getPositionOfItem
                    (categoryListNames.get(i).getName());   and works right cause my first spinner fills and selects correctly, but just have to perform click :(

Comment: So, if I get this right, your `positionOfItem` and loop counter `i` is technically the same value, right?

Comment: no, getPositionOfItem() go and find position of a name that I want to know. so after that spinner select that item. i is counter to count spinner size and categories. I think it's better to live this part cause works correctly and I double check in debug mode and return proper value.